# Answer requests using regularily collected and updated data

Tags: flask

I'm trying to use flask to answer http requests but the proccess of collecting and calculating the data I want to deliver to the client takes too long for the client to wait. It would also be inefficient to calculate information that is already up to date again for each request. I experimented using threading and flask to regularily update my data and send it to the client as it is in the memory on each request. Unfortunately weired stuff happened, multiple threads ran and the application was often restarted which forced me to recalculate the data. I'm searching for a solution with flask which provides a way to run code in regular intervals and ensures that the application is not restarted too often.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

def function_that_magically_runs_regularily_and_in_an_own_thread():
    global data
    data = expensive_update(data)

@app.route("/get_data")
def get_data():
    return jsonify(data)

data = Data()
function_that_magically_runs_regularily_and_in_an_own_thread()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: What are you trying to get at?  You want your web server to run some code periodically?

Comment: Yes, another way to achieve this would be to have a daemon running which runs code periodically to update the data in it's memory and write it's knowledge to the filesystem or a database. Flask could then get the data at each request and send it to the client. I obviously want to use only one process.

Comment: Not to be too abrasive, but stop throwing buzzwords around.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Why do you feel that Flask plays any part in this operation?

Comment: I just want to use flask as a web framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use an in-process cron like [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()

# Run background_work every 15 minutes
# only allowing one instance to run at a time
@scheduler.schedule_job('interval', max_instances=1, minutes=15)
def background_work():
    global data
    data = expensive_update(data)

data = Data()
background_work()  # Run it once to populate the data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    scheduler.start()
    app.run(debug=True)
```